# Occupation measure of Brownian motion and absolute continuity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

I have a question related to the occupation measure of a Brownian motion, which is defined as

$T_t(A)=\int_{0}^{t}{1_{A}(X_s)ds}$

for any set A where $X_t$ is a standard Brownian motion (or with linear drift).

One thing I know for sure about this measure is that it is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. What I'm wondering is the following: Consider a variation of the occupation measure, given as follows:

$T_t(A;f)=\int_{0}^{t}{1_{A}(X_s)\cdot f(X_s) ds}$

where f is a non-negative function ($f\geq0$) that makes $T_t(\cdot)$ be a measure on the real line.

Then is there a known condition on the function $f$ under which the measure $T_t(\cdot;f)$ is also absolute continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure? The obvious condition I can think of is that the function $f$ is a positive constant everywhere, but I'm wondering if there is a nontrivial condition.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (one-dimensional) Brownian motion admits "local times" (occupation-time densities) $L^x_t(\omega)$, adapted to the Brownian filtration, jointly continuous in $(x,t)$ (a.s.),
such that 
$$
\int_0^t g(X_s)\,ds =\int_{\Bbb R} g(x) L^x_t\,dx, \qquad\forall t\ge 0,
$$
almost surely. Here  $g$ is a Borel function that is non-negative or bounded (for example). With this fact in hand, the answer to your question should be clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Let me re-write my reply here: So I tried to follow your logic and proceed as follows: $T_t(A;f) = \int_{0}^{t}{1_{X_s \in A} \cdot f(X_s) ds} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{1_{x \in A} \cdot f(x) dL^{x}_t dx}$ From here, I can easily see that if the function $f$ is bounded (and the local time $L^{x}_{t}$), then $T_t(A;f)$ should be zero for any Lebesgue measure zero set A. Did I follow your point here? If it's correct, my follow-up question is: whether this argument works even if the function $f$ is not bounded (just non-negative and integrable, for example)?

Comment: I might have figured this out. So $T_t(A;f) = \int_{0}^{t}{1_{X_s \in A} \cdot f(X_s) ds} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1_{x \in A} \cdot f(x) L^{x}_t dx} = \int_{A}{f(x) L^{x}_t dx} = 0 $ if $\mu(A) = 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.